# Control Youtube on Android from another device

Tags: remote-control, youtube

Hopefully this should be fairly easy to do but I keep drawing a blank when searching for it.

I know it is pretty easy to control YouTube on the TV or PC from your phone  using [YouTube Pair](https://www.youtube.com/pair)
But is there a way to do it the other way round?

I have an android handset which is not being used for anything else so hoping to try to turn it into a chromecast type gadget but I only need audio out. I have the phone headphone socket linked up to the AUX input of the stereo in the kitchen. I've got Spotify installed which has built in support ([Spotify Connect feature](https://support.spotify.com/uk/learn-more/guides/#!/article/Spotify-Connect)) for playing music on other devices from a desktop or another phone.

I'm hoping to be able to do the same with Youtube playlists or just individual videos, especially since YT just added the auto-playlist feature.